# Smallest and largest topologies on $Y$ for which $f$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, and $f:X\to Y$ be a function. For a given
>    topology $\mathcal{T}_{X}$ on $X$, describe as well as you can the
>   smallest and largest topologies on $Y$ for which $f$ is continuous.

Should I give an example of a system $\mathcal{T}_{Y}$ that is a topology on $Y$ and then determing the smallest and largest topologies containing $\mathcal{T}_{Y}$?

Comment: For the smallest, consider $\mathcal{T}_Y = \{Y, \emptyset\}$, for $f$ to be continuous, $f^{-1}(Y)$ and $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$ must be open. Is it true?

Comment: For the largest $\mathcal{T}_Y$. Let $A \subseteq Y$. And we want to determine whether $A \in \mathcal{T}_Y$. For $f$ to be continuous it must hold: $A \in \mathcal{T}_Y \implies f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{T}_X$. The last condition is equivalent to $f^{-1}(A) \not\in \mathcal{T}_X \implies A \notin \mathcal{T}_Y,$ so for $A \subseteq Y$ we now see, when $A \in \mathcal{T}_Y$. You could f.e. take $\mathcal{T}_Y = \mathcal{P}_Y$ and remove the subsets of $Y$ not satisfying the condition. I didn't thought about all the details, so I'd rather not post this as an answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{T}_Y$ be a topology on $Y$. In order for $f$ to be continous we must have that for all $A$ in $\mathcal{T}_Y$ the preimage $f^{-1}(A)$ is in $\mathcal{T}_X$. This means that $\mathcal{T}_Y \subseteq \{A\,|\, A \subseteq  Y, f^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{T}_X\}$

As quapka explains the smallest is the indiscrete topology. Check that it is true.

To find the largest toplogy on $Y$ check whether $\{A\,|\, A \subseteq  Y, f^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{T}_X\}$ is a topology.