# Smallest and largest topologies on $X$ for which $f$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functions

This is a similar question to [LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541594/smallest-and-largest-topologies-on-y-for-which-f-is-continuous).

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, and $f:X\to Y$ be a function. For a given
>    topology $\mathcal{T}_{Y}$ on $Y$, describe as well as you can the
>   smallest and largest topologies on $X$ for which $f$ is continuous.

Let $\mathcal{T}_{X}$ be a topology on $X$. The function $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(V)\in \mathcal{T}_{X}$ for all $V\in \mathcal{T}_{Y}$. Since $f^{-1}(Y)\subseteq X$, I think I can define $\mathcal{A}_{1}=\{\emptyset, f^{-1}(Y)\}$, which is a topology on $X$. So letting $\mathcal{T}_{X}=\mathcal{A}_{1}$, the function $f$ is continuous and $\mathcal{A}_{1}$ a smallest topology on $X$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: for the largest topology, keep in mind that the any function from the discrete topology to any topological space is continuous

Comment: You don't need to explicitly include the empty set in $\mathcal A_1$. Since $\emptyset\in\mathcal T_Y$ you get it for free.

Comment: I misunderstood your definition of $\mathcal A_1$. It won't work because $f^{-1}(V)$ must be in $\mathcal T_X$ for all $V\in\mathcal T_Y$.

Comment: @JohnDouma If we take $V=Y\in \mathcal{T}_{Y}$, so $f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(Y)\subseteq X\in \mathcal{T}_{X}$.

Comment: @AjmalW What if $Y=\mathbb R$?. Is it enough for $f^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ to be open?

Answer (score 2):

This $A_1$ defined in the question is too small. Just making $f^{-1}(Y)$ open is not enough to make $f$ continuous. Instead, in order for $f$ to be continuous, the topology should not only contain $f^{-1}(Y)$ but all $f^{-1}(V)$ for each V open in Y.

In fact, the smallest topology for $f$ to be continuous is the quotient topology induced by $f$. The definition of quotient topology induced by $f$ is that a set U in X is open if and only if $U=f^{-1}(V)$ for some V open in Y. In other words, there is no other open set in X except those which are necessary to make $f$ continuous.

The largest topology on $X$, as is pointed out in the comment by @Alan, is the discrete topology. This is the largest possible topology on X and $f$ is definitely continuous under that topology.

Comment: I checked about the quotient topology, but we haven't been taught about it yet, We are learning about it in this week. Is it possible to answer it another way?

Comment: Hi. The definition of quotient topology induced by f is that a set U in X is open if and only if $U=f^{-1}(V)$ for some V open in Y. In other words, there is no other open set in X except those which are necessary to make f continuous. I will update these words into the answer. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @AjmalW I updated the answer. Wish it is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

For $f$ to be continuous we require $f^{-1}(V)$ to be open for all $V\in\mathcal T_Y$.

Therefore, the collection $\{f^{-1}(U): U\in\mathcal T_Y\}$ must be contained in any topology on $X$. Moreover, if we can show that $\mathcal T_X=\{f^{-1}(U): U\in\mathcal T_Y\}$ is a topology on $X$ then it must be the smallest.

To show $\mathcal T_X$ is a topology we must show that it contains $X$ and $\emptyset$. We must also show that it is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections.

$Y\in\mathcal T_Y$ and $f^{-1}(Y)=X\in\mathcal T_X$

$\emptyset\in\mathcal T_Y$ and $f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset\in\mathcal T_X$

If $\{f^{-1(}U_i)\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of open sets in $\mathcal T_X$ then $\cup_{i\in I}f^{-1}(U_i)=f^{-1}(\cup_{i\in I}U_i)\in\mathcal T_X$ because $\cup_{i\in I}U_i\in\mathcal T_Y$.

Finally, if $f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal T_X$ and $f^{-1}(V)\in\mathcal T_Y$ then $f^{-1}(U)\cap f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(U\cap V)\in\mathcal T_X$ because $U\cap V\in\mathcal T_Y$.